# Contact Number textfield form error in ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to insert the data into database in `ROR`, for phone number i have taken field integer..But it is only taking 9 numeric digits..if i try to put 10 digits.It provides error as.

> Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column 'Telephone' at row 1:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (
    Email,
    Message,
    NAME,
    SUBJECT,
    Telephone,
    created_at,
    updated_at
)
VALUES
    (
        'ghfghf',
        'daaswwd ffdd',
        'ghfghf',
        'fggfhg',
         9234567899,
        '2016-07-27 05:47:43',
        '2016-07-27 05:47:43'
    )
```

But if I put numbers as `1234567890`..it is inserting data properly but not for any other number.. `9878675645`

Comment: are you using Mysql database..??

Comment: What is the datatype of `Telephone`?

Comment: Change your column type to `varchar`. `ALTER TABLE contacts MODIFY COLUMN Telephone VARCHAR(100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column 'Telephone' at row 1:

Change column type for `telephone` to string as integer doesn't support that long range

```
def up
  change_column :contacts, :telephone, :string
end

def down
  change_column :contacts, :telephone, :integer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the phone numbers for an actual operation, you should store them as string and not as integer. Imagine that you need to store an international number that would look like `001234545677788`. If it is an integer, the two leading zeros will not be kept. Also, if you want to use the standard notation for international access `+1234566454545` you would be missing the `+` sign.

Comment: By the way, standard international numbers may contain up to 16 digits (or even more). Consider what would be the equivalent integer size...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the type of your data you are using integer and integer have an interval from :
-2147483648  TO  2147483647

and don't store phone number as numbers use VARCHAR  because when you write a number that start with 0 that zero on the left will be gone 0099 ---> 99